# How to remove the blinking cursor after selecting an option from dropdown in by ng-select in Angular?

Tags: angular, npm, dropdown, angular-ngselect, text-cursor

i am using ng-select in Angular 5 for dropdown. After selecting an option the blinking cursor should be vanished or it's position should be at the end of the text. But after selecting any option from dropdown the blinking cursor goes at the start position of the text. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: For an example?

Comment: @hrishikesh I can't upload screen shot.

Comment: after selecting an option from the dropdown cursor inside the dropdown the blinking cursor should be after the last character of the text. but it moved to the first after selecting any option

Comment: I got your issue and have an answer for you hope this work for you!

Answer (score 9):

I mean it's not an issue but it's a feature of ng-select,

as it by default lets you to search or enables you the autocomplete functionality,

to stop this or to hide the autocomplete functionality you need to pass one extra attribute called

```
[searchable]="false"
```

this will disable the cursor and autocomplete functionality will also not work 
hope this helps you

here is the [plunkr](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-cvypo7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)  also here is the full [documentation](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/forms) for the same

Comment: If this solution worked for you , you can accept this as an answer which will be easier for someone  looking for similar problem

Comment: This worked for me. It disabled the cursor of the dropdown select.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code in CSS

```
    .ng-select .ng-select-container .ng-value-container .ng-input>input {
caret-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Worked fine, although a selector as simple as `.ng-has-value input` was sufficient for me.